# How do I use Http Digest Auth with volley on Android

Tags: android, android-volley, http-authentication, http-digest

I want to use **Http Digest** with `Volley`. So far I have used the following code:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String creds = String.format("%s:%s","admin","mypass");
    String auth = "Digest " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    params.put("Authorization", "Digest " +auth);
    return params;

}
```

So far I get a response from server as wrong credentials which means that authentication is working but only wrong credentials are getting passed. But my credentials are right.

Comment: Sounds good. I don't see any question, though.

Comment: I am not getting any results. Only wrong credentials. I think the way I am passing the credentials is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You use Base64 encoding which is fine for Basic Auth but this is not how digest works.
Digest & Basic Auth specs can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617

the newer Digest Specs can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616

And nice extra explanation on wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

For Volley implementation of Digest Auth you can use:
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Framework/platform/com_gm_android_volleyHttpDigestStack_java.htm

You will just need to pass this http stack when you create your Network which you then use to create your RequestQueue:

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    requestQueue = new RequestQueue(
            new DiskBasedCache(rootDir),
            new BasicNetwork(new HttpDigestStack())
    );
    requestQueue.start();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please.

Comment: All roads lead to this code, but not a single decent answer on how to implement it!

Comment: @PassKit answer edited :) I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how exactly do you import the code from http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Framework/platform/com_gm_android_volleyHttpDigestStack_java.htm? There does not seem to be any documentation on how to add this to a project which is where I am struggling.

Comment: Create a class in your project then copy&pate that code :)

Comment: In addition to the HttpDigestStack class you also need to bring in the Headers class http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Framework/platform/com_gm_android_volleyHeaders_java.htm in recent android versions the apache libraries are not in by default so you must add "compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'" to your gradle